# reproduce "fatal error: concurrent map read and map write"

Tags: dictionary, go, concurrency

I'm debugging my program for a bug `fatal error: concurrent map read and map write`. The program can be simplified as:

```
package main

import (
    "sync"
    "time"
)

func read(channelMap *map[int]chan bool, key int, mutex *sync.Mutex) {
    mutex.Lock()
    (*channelMap)[key] = make(chan bool, 1)
    mutex.Unlock()

    defer func() {
        mutex.Lock()
        delete((*channelMap), key)
        mutex.Unlock()
    }()

    select {
    case <-(*channelMap)[key]:
        {
        }
    case <-time.After(time.Second):
        {
        }
    }
}

func write(channelMap *map[int]chan bool, key int, mutex *sync.Mutex) {
    mutex.Lock()
    if channel, exist := (*channelMap)[key]; exist {
        channel <- true
    }
    mutex.Unlock()
}

func main() {
    mutex := &sync.Mutex{}
    channelMap := make(map[int]chan bool)

    for i := 0; i < 100; i++ {
        go func() {
            for {
                read(&channelMap, 0, mutex)
                time.Sleep(time.Millisecond)
            }
        }()
        go func() {
            for {
                write(&channelMap, 0, mutex)
                time.Sleep(time.Millisecond)
            }
        }()
    }

    time.Sleep(10 * time.Minute)
}
```

For this program, only `channelMap` and `mutex` are shared in different functions, everything else is parameterized.

There are multiple `read` and `write`, who have access to `channelMap`, a map storing `channel`. `read` waits for a value from a certain channel for some given time (1 second in the example code), and `write` send a value into the same channel when this channel exist in the `channelMap`.

Every access to `channelMap` has been protected by a shared `sync.Mutex` and the only exception is

```
    select {
    case <-(*channelMap)[key]:
        {
        }
    case <-time.After(time.Second):
        {
        }
    }
```

I think this is the only vulnerability but with the simplified program I still couldn't reproduce the bug. Can someone explain to me the possible logical flaw in this program?

Comment: You’re reading the map without using the mutex. You can’t do that if the map needs to be protected by the mutex.

Comment: The [Race Detector](https://golang.org/doc/articles/race_detector) detects and reports the problem.

Comment: Why was this closed for non-reproducibility?   It's totally reproducible, and `go test -race` finds it.  The answer below is correct and complete.

Answer (score 1):

When modifying a data structure concurrently, all reads and writes must be protected by a mutex.

This part: `case <-(*channelMap)[key]:` accesses `channelMap` without holding a lock.

Concurrent access to a data structure is possible in two situations:

- Zero writers, one or more readers, or
- One writer, zero readers.

Comment: technologically speaking, it is ok to concurrently reading the same data structure at the same time (as long as there is no concurrent write) without any protection.

Comment: @leafbebop Did I say it otherwise?

Comment: @rustyx I think there is confusion about where this guarantee comes from (the language, the OS, or the hardware itself)